# Check mark disappeared from dropdowns

Tags: macos, ui

In all dropdowns both in the browser and in the system the checkmark has disappeared. This is macOS Sierra and every dropdown in Chrome, Safari or any app looks like this:

[image]

Anything I can do? I tried rebooting. Also I had San Francisco Developer version installed, removed it, nothing changed. Installed the latest macOS public beta, nothing.

**Updated**

Tried to `Restore System Fonts` but it did not find any problems.

[image]

**Fixed**

In fact right after that I have installed the new macOS beta and it got fixed. Maybe all I was needed is to reboot after restoring system fonts. So I am marking this as solved.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting? It's cliche, but may well solve it.

Comment: I tried everything, I had San Francisco developer version installed, removed it, nothing changed. Even installed the latest macOS beta, nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Font Book, choose File → Restore Standard Fonts….

Comment: Didn't know you can do that, thanks. However nothing changed. Let me try the fresh macOS beta...

Comment: I'd use this solution with caution. I had the same problem, and 'Restore Standard Fonts' plus a reboot fixed it, however, subsequently I found several new problem. For one, emoji's stopped rendering at all. Turned out the 'Apple Color Emoji.tff' font in /System/Library/Fonts was moved to /System/Library/Fonts (Removed). Also, though I can't absolutely say this was the cause, after reboot many applications would not launch (just bounce in the Dock indefinitely). Rebuilding the font cache via `sudo atsutil databases -remove` plus a reboot resolved that issue.