# Identify Missing System Font

Tags: macos, google-chrome, font

After installing Sierra and a number of other fonts from Google Web Fonts, I now see the 'question mark' against any list items either within the actual system UI and other applications such as Chrome.

[image: System Example]
[image: Chrome Example]

**Edit:**
I have already attemped two possible solutions:

1. [Font Book for Mac: Restore standard fonts](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH21410?locale=en_US)
2. [How to Restore Default Fonts on Mac](http://sayzlim.net/restore-default-fonts-mac)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `sudo atsutil databases -remove`, then reboot.

atsutil is the CLI for the font registration system. Resetting the database can help clear up errors like this. Also see [Check mark disappeared from dropdowns](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/262680/37797).

Comment: Thank you so much. I would not have thought to search for "check mark" as I associated the question mark with missing fonts that don't work through browsers if you have noscripts or alike, enabled. Now I know :) Thanks again.